# Trying to get use results of query in another query... possible?

Tags: mysql, select, join

table *orders_total* with data like so:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+
| orders_total_id | orders_id |   title   |  value  |    class    |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+
|               1 |         1 | Sub-total | 34.0000 | ot_subtotal |
|               2 |         1 | Tax       | 2.38    | ot_tax      |
|               3 |         2 | Sub-total | 12.0000 | ot_subtotal |
|               4 |         2 | Tax       | 0.60    | ot_tax      |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------------+
```

table *orders* with data like so:

```
+-----------+----------+
| orders_id | currency |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 | USD      |
|         2 | CAD      |
+-----------+----------+
```

I want to see:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+
| orders_id | currency |  subtotal |  tax  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+
|         1 | USD      | 34.0000   | 2.38  |
|         2 | CAD      | 12.0000   | 0.60  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------+
```

I want to grab the two values (where class="ot_subtotal") and insert them into my select for the orders table.  But I can't seem to figure out how to query down one table within another query without mysql choking. I've read plenty of questions/answers about this but they all have some detail that throws me off.  I think I need a specific example to move forward.

++EDIT++
So sorry, I over-simplified the question and didn't end up asking the question I meant to.  I've adjusted above.  the trouble I'm having is getting BOTH classes into one output.

Comment: How many different types of `class` are possible is it always `ot_subtotal` and `ot_tax` ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty No, there are a few more.

Comment: And the result should be only for those 2 types ? ignoring other values ?

Comment: Afraid not.  There's also "shipping" and "shipping tax" that I need.  There are also several others that I don't need.

Comment: Just added an answer you can also add shipping and shipping tax into the query and it should work. something as `max(case when ot.class = 'shipping' then value end) as shipping,...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only concern about generating the pivot table for `ot_subtotal` and `ot_tax` then the following should do the trick

```
select
o.orders_id,
o.currency,
max(case when ot.class = 'ot_subtotal' then value end) as subtotal,
max(case when ot.class = 'ot_tax' then value end) as tax
from orders o
join orders_total ot on ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
group by o.orders_id
```

Comment: That gets me a helluva lot closer anyway!  Thanks so much.  Now I have to go look up what that 'end' is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join of both the tables as:

```
Select o1.orders_id, o2.currency, o1.value from 
orders_total o1 inner join orders o2 on o1.orders_id = o2.orders_id 
where o1.class = "ot_subtotal"
```

Comment: I'm so sorry.  Once I saw your answer I thought you completely misunderstood my question but then I see I forgot to finish the output table!  i've updated it.  It is the SECOND row-to-column that I'm having trouble figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the `orders_id` column:

```
SELECT ot.orders_id, currency, value
FROM   orders_total ot
JOIN   orders o ON ot.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE  class = 'ot_subtotal'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
INSERT INTO `new_table`(`orders_id`, `currency`, `value`) 
SELECT o.orders_id,o.currency,ot.value FROM `orders` o 
left join orders_total ot on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id   WHERE ot.class = 'ot_subtotal'
```

Comment: is there a way to do that with it creating the table as well?  I just get an error that the new_table doesn't exist.

Comment: you need to create that table, so add this first `CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
 `orders_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `currency` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
 `value` float NOT NULL
) `

Comment: That worked, but I guess you didn't see my edit before you answered. Sorry.